# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).dialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И WARNING по возможности. Никак не получается.

```html
<script>
    var cfg_load = null;
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ftp2d').submit();
            cfg_load= $('#cfg_load').css({'box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444', '-moz-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444', '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444'}).dialog({minHeight: 285, autoOpen:false, minWidth: 485, title: 'Импорт конфигурации'});
            $('#cfg_load_opt').css({'border' : '0px double black','box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444', '-moz-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444', '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0px 0px 0px #444'}).tabs();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: у вас ошибка в javascript коде а не в php...

Comment: Я на пару минут потерялся. Какая связь между консолью браузера с ошибками в Javascript и кодом на PHP?

Comment: Извините, ошибся. А как вы узнали что в скрипте, и в каком?

Comment: @therainycat, исправил пост.

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову  - dialog из JqueryUI, который не подключен

Comment: @therainycat, да вроде подключен.

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>